# Split Text From the Last Space before the 35th position Character in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

e.g. Supplier Name - NANJING BANGSHING PRECISION MACHINERY TE

I want to break this Name from the last space before the 35th position.

In this Case 35th Position is - 'E' in MACHINERY, and I want to split it from the Space before it.

i.e.

```
NANJING BANGSHING PRECISION - Cell A1
MACHINERY TE - Cell B2
```

Currently I am finding the position of 2nd last space(For any Supplier Name going above 35 Characters, as the names are not longer than 70 chars), in order to complete my task. However, it's not a good practice.

```
=FIND("^"|SUBSTITUTE(A1|" "|"^"|LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1|" "|""))-1))
```

to find the position

```
NANJING BANGSHING PRECISION - Cell A1
MACHINERY TE - Cell B2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AGGREGATE can return the position of the last space before the 35th position. Use with REPLACE to remove unwanted characters.

```
'first part
=REPLACE(A2, AGGREGATE(14, 7, ROW($1:$35)/(MID(A2, ROW($1:$35), 1)=" "), 1), LEN(A2), "")
'second part
=REPLACE(A2, 1, AGGREGATE(14, 7, ROW($1:$36)/(MID(A2, ROW($1:$36), 1)=" "), 1), "")
```

It was a little unclear on what to do if the 35th position was actually a space. The above uses it as the stop. If this is not desired behavior, change the 35's to 34.

Comment: It worked like a Charm... Thank you for the help. :)
Just need to understand how the formula is working with ROW and AGGREGATE function. Will appreciate if you can help me to get that.

Comment: row(1:35) is used to get a series of numbers from 1 to 35. Anything that is a space is the position number; anything else is an error. Aggregate's 14 takes the largest of these numbers, the 7 tells Aggregate to ignore errors.